# Best way to create 3d matrix of variables in PULP

Tags: python, pulp

I want to create a list of variables in PULP that will follow the following structure. There can be any number of types, and each type can have any number of subcat, however each type/subcat must have exactly 2 numbers.

```
type subcat number
1    A      1
1    A      2
1    B      1
1    B      2
2    A      1
2    A      2
```

I want to create one matrix of LpVariables that look like this, where each item in the list represets each type and is a matrix of subcat X number dimensions.

```
vars = [["1A1", "1A2"
         "1B1", "1B2"],
        ["2A1", "2A2"]]
```

I tried just looping through and creating individual LpVariables using the code below, but then it will create a bunch of individual variables right? So it would be difficult if I wanted to do a sum based on type or subcat.

```
for type in typeList:
    for subcat in subcatList:
        for num in range(2):
            varName = type + ':' + subcat + ":" + num
            LpVariable(varName, cat='Binary')
```

What would be the best way for me to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest something like the example below.  I used 3-tuples of (mode/submode/time) with the same structure you stated.  Note that this approach creates a "sparse" matrix that is more compact (better for model) than a full matrix if there are unused elements.  For example, there is no `(train, business, day)` combination expressed or available.

First an aside...  For clarification, there are 4 "terms" in play here, and `pulp` can let you do some confusing things with variable names

1. The variable **name**.  In my model it is "price"
2. The sets that are used to index the variable.  My model has 3 (mode, submode, time)
3. The domain (legal values) for the variable
4. The value of the variable (determined by solving the model)

`pulp` lets you name the variable instances individually by the index values, which I think is wayyy confusing and tough to work with.  This is what you have in your sample code.  Folks do this and then do backflips with string operations to re-construct the variable names when needed.  Messy.  I prefer the `.dicts()` method that allows you to just pass in the indexing structure and go from there.

The general approach is:  construct your indexing structure somehow, flatten it out into a set of indexes, pass that to the variable constructor.

Then:  when & if you need a subset, you can create one on-the-fly with a comprehension or filter, or just do something creative with your original data structure objects.

##### Code:

```
# pulp variable maker

import pulp
from itertools import chain

# some transportation data:  mode / submode / time 

structure = { 'plane': {'first', 'business', 'coach'},
              'train': {'first', 'coach'}
            }

times = ['day', 'night']

idxs = {(mode, submode, time) 
        for mode in structure.keys() 
        for submode in structure[mode] 
        for time in times}

# make an indexed variable with the .dicts method
price = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('price', idxs, cat='Continuous')

# create the problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem('sample', pulp.LpMinimize)

# set the objective (minimize the sum of all prices)
prob += pulp.lpSum(price)

# SOME GOOFY CONSTRAINTS...

# let's limit the plane tickets to less than $500....
# whip up a subset on-the-fly with a comprehension or a filter
plane_subset = {idx for idx in idxs if idx[0] == 'plane'}
for idx in plane_subset:
    prob += price[idx] <= 500


# all night tickets must cost at least $100
night_subset = {idx for idx in idxs if idx[2] == 'night'}
for idx in night_subset:
    prob += price[idx] >= 100

# all the submodes in daytime must sum to less than $300 for each mode...
for mode in structure.keys():
    prob += sum(price[mode, submode, 'day'] for submode in structure[mode]) <= 300

print(prob)
```

##### Output:

```
sample:
MINIMIZE
1*price_('plane',_'business',_'day') + 1*price_('plane',_'business',_'night') + 1*price_('plane',_'coach',_'day') + 1*price_('plane',_'coach',_'night') + 1*price_('plane',_'first',_'day') + 1*price_('plane',_'first',_'night') + 1*price_('train',_'coach',_'day') + 1*price_('train',_'coach',_'night') + 1*price_('train',_'first',_'day') + 1*price_('train',_'first',_'night') + 0
SUBJECT TO
_C1: price_('plane',_'business',_'day') <= 500

_C2: price_('plane',_'first',_'night') <= 500

_C3: price_('plane',_'coach',_'night') <= 500

_C4: price_('plane',_'first',_'day') <= 500

_C5: price_('plane',_'coach',_'day') <= 500

_C6: price_('plane',_'business',_'night') <= 500

_C7: price_('plane',_'first',_'night') >= 100

_C8: price_('plane',_'coach',_'night') >= 100

_C9: price_('plane',_'business',_'night') >= 100

_C10: price_('train',_'first',_'night') >= 100

_C11: price_('train',_'coach',_'night') >= 100

_C12: price_('plane',_'business',_'day') + price_('plane',_'coach',_'day')
 + price_('plane',_'first',_'day') <= 300

_C13: price_('train',_'coach',_'day') + price_('train',_'first',_'day') <= 300

VARIABLES
price_('plane',_'business',_'day') free Continuous
price_('plane',_'business',_'night') free Continuous
price_('plane',_'coach',_'day') free Continuous
price_('plane',_'coach',_'night') free Continuous
price_('plane',_'first',_'day') free Continuous
price_('plane',_'first',_'night') free Continuous
price_('train',_'coach',_'day') free Continuous
price_('train',_'coach',_'night') free Continuous
price_('train',_'first',_'day') free Continuous
price_('train',_'first',_'night') free Continuous

[Finished in 84ms]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this example, if you wanted to add order to the LP, what would be the best way? Like if all of your transportations were ordered, let's say if the price increases by $10 if you go from using first class to coach, and the price decreases by $10 if you go from business to coach. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: actually its probably easier if i create a different question with the actual LP im trying to create instead

Comment: Agree w/ the second comment.  You are introducing a new question on logic and constraint construction, which might depend on several things.  If this answered your original question, it is customary to "accept" the answer by hitting the check-mark next to it to close the issue, and/or up-vote it.